# How to access property of parent in validation attribute

Tags: validation, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, validationattribute

In my code below I want to check with AttributeValidation if a field is given dependent on a property of its parent element. The comment in the class

> RequiredIfParentState1

describes my question best.

```
public class ChildModel()
{
   [RequiredIfParentState1]
   public string ImRequired { get; set; } 
}

public class ParentViewModel()
{
   public int state { get; set; }
   public ChildModel child = new ChildModel();
}

public class RequiredIfParentState1: ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
{
   RequiredIfParentState1()
   {

   }
   void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
   {

   }

   protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object i_value, ValidationContext i_context)
   {
      var element = i_context.ObjectInstance;

      if(i_value == null && //what do i have to put here to check if the state is 1?)
      {
         return new ValidationResult($"Field is Required in state 1.");
      }

      return ValidationResult.Success;
   }
}
```

Comment: You cannot. The `ValidationContext` is the properties class (in your case `ChildModel`). It has no knowledge of any parent class

Comment: I was afraid to hear that.... any good practice for a workaround?

Comment: Easiest to just have all the properties in a single view model

Comment: ok thanks... But in my case this will be a really big one with multiple hundred lines - I also thought about creating in each "ChildModel" a parent property which is stored within the constructor...

Comment: Why not just include a `bool IsRequired` property in `ChildModel` and set it based on the value of `state` from the parent model

Comment: That's a good one and woth considering. However this is my first project with Asp.net core... I came to the conclusion that I made a big mistake in the design phase and do not split hard enough between my models and viewmodels. As I try to live the approach "fix it - don't hack it" I'm now thinking about redesigning and therefore resolving the issue with an absolute flat viewmodel...

Answer (score 0):

I feel this is the wrong approach.

An object being in a valid state is one thing (required fields and type checking), but handling business logic is a separate concern.

You could write a validation service, that examines the model in detail, checking business logic concerns, and build up a list of errors.

Where errors are found you can return these in your response.

Comment: In my view I have a big process where I ask the user to put in different properties in different steps of the process. This is what I am trying to achieve. The current status of the process is stored in a property on the parentmodel and only in this status the user is required to fill in some of the properties of the child model. (he cannot fill all which are required, because he might not see it as he is not so far enough in the process yet). However it was a business requirement to be able to lookback to a earlier step in the process without losing unsaved changes